# What should i do if the school made a mistake on my grade? Failed but when i checked i really passed

Tags: grades

I had been informed that my final grade was 74.86 and I did not pass. So I repeated that subject and paid $2000 for that subject. I passed the said repeated subject. Yesterday, I was browsing through all my final grades for the courses I took. Upon coming up with the MED SURG1 subject that I supposedly failed, my grade there was actually 75.01 which means I actually passed. I printed that screen as my proof in any case they deny or change it. Thank you and i hope to resolve this matter with some advice here.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Would you have been able to check your grade before retaking the course? If so, why didn't you check? What country are you in? Do instructors at your institution tend to have leeway in assigning grades, or are all grade assignments formulaic based strictly on point totals?

Comment: Aren't grading systems that think they can measure quality to within 1/100 of a percent wonderful?......NOT.

Comment: What's your grade of the second time? Are you sure 75.01 is the grade of the first time, not the second time?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably nothing to do and a complaint will probably be ignored. This is sad and you are out some time and money. But, if you learned a bit more in the second taking you have some, perhaps small, compensation. And if the new grade is a bit higher it can help later, perhaps. Also, the course sounds pretty important for someone in the medical (or related) profession.

You could have a discussion with the dean or the head of department about it and, perhaps you could get some financial credit against a future course, but not likely more than that.

Good luck. Sorry you are caught in such a rigid system.

Comment: If you're going to make a binary distinction for some purpose between "passing" and "failing" there must be a threshold somewhere, whether it's rigid or not just means different students are treated  differently with respect to the threshold.